# NiFi 1.11.4 on Windows fails to start because of an invalid concurrent tasks setting on a Processor

Tags: windows, concurrency, apache-nifi, startup

My problem is that Nifi won't complete its' startup. After about 40s the CMD window atarted by run-nifi.bat disappears. So the GUI doesn't connect and I cannot change the property. Anyone know if I can edit a file somewhere to change the property so that Nifi will start? If so where is the file?
This is the salient line in the nifi-app.log:

org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.FlowSynchronizationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set Concurrent Tasks to 0 for component b480dc3c-0173-1000-fd71-482c5a9f6526 because Scheduling Strategy is not Event Driven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Msj I usually do not recommend doing this, but you can extract the flow.xml.gz and make modifications. Be surgically careful, if you make mistakes you can completely break the flow.  Make a backup of file before working on it just in case.  Repack the file when done, and make sure the permissions remain the same (chown user and chmod ).

Answer (score 0):

1- make a backup of your conf/flow.xml.gz
2- uncompress your flow.xml.gz
3- look for the processor with id: b480dc3c-0173-1000-fd71-482c5a9f6526

```
<id>b480dc3c-0173-1000-fd71-482c5a9f6526</id>
```

change the concurrent task to 1 instead of 0:

```
<maxConcurrentTasks>1</maxConcurrentTasks>
```

compress it back and launch Nifi